# Mark a row across different `div`s with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I have a layout of two `div`s that are horizontally stacked.
Each of them contains a row of elements.

How can I make one of these rows make selectable (so that one may copy them to his clipboard, in this example: `Item 1 Item2`) with the mouse with jQuery?
At best the user shouldn't see a difference and just do the normal process (mouse press > mouse move > mouse release).

Unfortunately, I am not able to edit the Html.

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <p>Item 1</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <p>Item 2</p>
</div>
```

If you try to do it now, it marks half of each column.
[**Live Preview (JSFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/netme/36dWe/)

[image]

Comment: Make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please, I don't want to go to your site.

Comment: I think this is not possible with that DOM structure. You say you can not edit the HTML – but since you can use jQuery, you can change the _DOM_.

Comment: Sorry what exactly do you mean by "markable"?

Comment: I also don't see anything highlighting on your page, as there is no js at all. Can you please make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the code you have so far?

Comment: Just FYI the style tag on your demo page should be within the HEAD of the page.

Comment: @Dom selectable with your mouse, I added some info.

Comment: With the HTML you have it is simply not possible. You would have to weigh how important this is vs the potential clunkyness of modifying the DOM with Javascript to make this specific thing possible.

Comment: I've generated playground in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/netme/36dWe/

Comment: @poitroae now that you clarified, the answer is it isn't possible. Use a `<table>` for tabular data is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting tabular data into two separate dividers. No matter how you style the dividers, the paragraphs will never be side-by-side when making a text selection. One thing you can do is convert it into a table if you aren't able to change the markup:

```
/* Count the total number of children within the first divider.
 * This assumes both will always be equal. */
var total = $('div:first-child').children().length,

/* Create the table. */
    table = $('<table><tbody></tbody></table>');

/* Loop from 0 to total. */
for(i=0;i<total;i++)
{
    /* Create the table row. */
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>'),
    /* Index will be i + 1, store this as new variable. */
        j = i + 1;

    /* Loop through each matching nth-child. */
    $('div p:nth-child(' + j + ')').each(function() {
        /* Create the table cell. */
        var td = $('<td></td>');

        /* Set the cell's text to the paragraph's text. */
        td.text($(this).text());

        /* Append cell to row. */
        td.appendTo(tr);
    })

    /* Append row to table's tbody. */
    tr.appendTo($('tbody', table));
}

/* Append table to body. */
table.appendTo('body');

/* Remove dividers. */
$('div').remove();
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/36dWe/2/).